# How to avoid sharing Email on algolia, Using Firbase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am using Firebase functions to create Algolia indices for the full-text search app

here is how I create an index when someone post on Firebase:

```js
export const onListingCreated = functions.firestore
  .document('Listings/{listingId}')
  .onCreate((snap, ctx) => {
    return index.saveObject({
      objectID: snap.id,
      ...snap.data(),
    })
  })

//...snap.data() has - AdTitle:"House" Email:"example@gmail.com"
//this works well the index is created like this on algolia
```

But I want to avoid sharing the email

I tried it Like this:

```js
export const onListingCreated = functions.firestore
  .document('Listings/{listingId}')
  .onCreate((snap, ctx) => {
    return index.saveObject({
      objectID: snap.id,
      ...snap.data().AdTitle,
    })
  })

//on algolia the index was created like:
//0:H
//1:o
//2:u
//3:s
//4:e

I wanted to be AdTitle: "House"
```

Is there a way to avoid sharing sensitive information on algolia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `snap.data().AdTitle` is the string `House` and you are spreading over the string which makes your output object look like that.
Once you spread a string it is converted to an array. For example `House` is  converted to `["H", "o", "u", "s", "e"]` Now in javascript arrays are also type of object so when you try `{...["H", "o", "u", "s", "e"]}` it takes `["H", "o", "u", "s", "e"]` as `{ 0: "H", 1: "o", 2: "u", 3: "s", 4: "e" }` and spreads over that object giving what you have mentioned

```js
let randomString = 'House'
let obj = {...randomString} //converts to array and then spreads the array
console.log(obj)

let arr = [...randomString]
console.log(arr)
let obj2 = {...arr}
console.log(obj2) //obj and obj2 give same result
```

Instead what you can do is

```js
    let randomString = 'House'
    let obj = {AdTitle: randomString}
    console.log(obj)
```

Or you can delete the `Email` property from the data object and then use your usual implementation

```js
  .onCreate((snap, ctx) => {
    const dataObj = snap.data()
    delete dataObj.Email
    return index.saveObject({
      objectID: snap.id,
      ...dataObj,
    })
  })
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete more than 1 fields I Tried to write delete twice but it only deletes the first one only?

Comment: you should be able to delete more than 1 field. just like a normal object

Comment: Thank you for responding, Yeah I also thought it would but it just delete the first one only.

Comment: any console logs? which field were you trying to delete

Comment: ooh Yes, It worked, it was not working because I included a (Comma) after the first delete, again Thank you for responding, you really helped me.